# create default html5 button css for a div?

Tags: html, css

I am using html5, and I want to make a div exact like default html5 button. Is there any way to make a div look like same as default button with css?

Comment: Yes, take the styling of that button and apply it to a div.

Comment: how can you please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `appearance` property of **CSS3** for that:

```css
div{
    appearance: button; /* CSS3 */ 
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* Safari and Chrome and opera */
    -moz-appearance: button; /* Firefox */
    -ms-appearance: button; /* Internet Explorer */
}
```

```html
<div>button</div>
```

Comment: Just a note: Your solution doesn't work in IE and opera - [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Comment: `appearance: button; /* CSS3 */ 

-webkit-appearance: button; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-appearance: button; /* Firefox */
-ms-appearance: button; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-appearance: button; /* Opera */`

Comment: @keshu_vats IE and Opera don't support `appearance` at all so using _prefixes_ won't work.